# What is the commented backlash hack?

Tags: html, css, macos

How does the commented backslash hack actually work?
I get the vague idea that, because of the backslash (for some reason), Mac ignores 
the following rules.

That's what I've read here: http://www.sam-i-am.com/work/sandbox/css/mac_ie5_hack.html

> ```
> #isnotMacIE5 { display: none;  }
> #isMacIE5 { display: block; background-color: #060; color: #fff; }
>
> /* commented backslash hack v2 \*/
> #isnotMacIE5 { display: block; background-color: #060; color: #fff; }
> #isMacIE5 { display: none; }
> /* end hack */
> ```

Why do we still include the `\#isMacIE5 { display: none; }`, if the Mac doesn't see it anyway?

Comment: Think you need to look at more up to date tutorials rather than trying to support a browser that hasn't been released in 15 years

Comment: Yeah... Just reading some old blogs, and didn't quite understand them, so I'd thought I'd ask. :)

Comment: It's just different browsers have different quirks when reading css, most have some sort of quirk that will allow you to target that browser only - most of these hacks are just exposing these quirks so if your element looks different in one browser, you can add extra styling just for that browser to bring it back in line with the rest of them.  Most modern browsers are pretty good though and rendering has got a lot closer so there isn't as much need for these types of hacks anymore - mainly just ie11 and safari that need them now

Comment: How do we specify specific browsers in css?

Comment: sorry I read your last comment wrong - I use my server side language to get the browser by using Request.Browser (c#) and then append it to my body tag as a class so I can target .safari, .ie, etc.  If you want to see how others do it - google something like ie11 only css hack

Answer (score 1):

> How does the commented backslash hack actually work?

IE for Mac (which won't run on modern Macs and hasn't been supported by Microsoft for almost a decade and a half) doesn't recognise `\*/` as the end of a comment.

This means that the last two rulesets in your example are treated as being inside the comment that starts with `/* commented backslash hack v2` and the `*/` from `recover from hack */` is treated as the end of that first comment.

> Why do we still include the `#isMacIE5 { display: none; }`, if the Mac doesn't see it anyway?

To hide the content that should be shown only on IE5/Mac from browsers which are not IE5/Mac.

Comment: Thanks! So does this hack still work? And is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Portable — If you can find anybody who is still running IE5/Mac then, yes, it still works (and they should get a new computer).